# How do I remove the extra padding when displaying the MasterDetail Master view

Tags: xamarin.forms, iphone-x

When opening the Master portion of a Xamarin Forms MasterDetail window in Landscape mode on iPhoneX it looks like the padding meant to accommodate the safe area is not removed, resulting in a huge gap between the hamburger and master view.  This does not exist running on an iPhone 8.

iPhone X:

[image: iPhone X hamburger]

iPhone 8:

[image: iPhone 8 hamburger]

Also, the color of the safe area to the left of the master area is the same color as the detail view, how do I make the colors of the master view extend into this area?

Answer (score 0):

For the color to extend you just have to set the background color of your page and as for the insets, you can adjust them.

```
public YourPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
    BackgroundColor = Color.YourColor;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var inset = On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
    inset.Left = 24;
    Padding = inset;
}
```

Keep in mind if your app can rotate between portrait and landscape you may have to `override OnSizeAllocated` to handle setting the insets there as well.

Comment: I don't see how setting the BackgroundColor to a single color is going to extend the color from the Master view into the left safe area since it is not one solid color.

Comment: If you want all colors all the way across you're going to have to set the inset to 0 or remove the SafeArea entirely and add margins for the contents of your views like on what looks like the contents of the ViewCell inside your ListView so that the notch doesn't overlay the content.